# WSO2 API Manager with ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

In API Manager, I pass APIs in API Manager with respective services, also after reading documentacion of API Manager version 3.0.0 (https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/GettingStarted/overview/), I know in Publisher there exists a ESB, also in my case I work with this cases I think is part of ESB:

- WSO2 OAuth Mediator(JAR).
- File JSON by WSO2 OAuth Mediator, with endpoints referents to API's I'm cosuming.
- In publisher page I add Custom Policies in request or response.

But existing WSO2 Enterprise Integrator (EI) version 6.6.0, this component have a ESB.

My questions are:

1. In my case, really I work with ESB?
2. How to integrate API Manager with EI?

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 API Manager gateway is built on top of Synapse engine which is the same engine used in WSO2 EI (ESB). Using API Manager you can do simple mediation. But if you want to do any complex mediation, then you should use EI (ESB) along with API Manager.